# Migration from keychain access

Tags: keychain

I would like to migrate from mac os X to Ubuntu.

All seems to be ok, except for keychain. Is there any script which migrates them from Apple "Keychain Access" to "Seahorse"?

Comment: IMO you only need to export the related keys and import them into seahorse. Nothing special.

Comment: yes, but I don't think how to export these keys... the GUI apple interface doesn't allow it.

Comment: I would ask in [apple.se] how to export the keychain, after that importing is pretty straight forward in seahorse.

Comment: yes, of course. But I was thinking there was "all-on-one scribe".